# Ruby on rails HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth-facebook

I am implementing a site where i will use **omniauth-facebook with devise gem**. I have followed all the instructions from this link https://github.com/rails-camp/facebook-omniauth-demo and also finished set up facebook app.Every time I am getting this error from the browser "**This site can’t provide a secure connection**".
From the rails console what I can see is:

**HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>**

Are there any solution?

Comment: seems like your site is on http, but callback tries to reach https, that's why puma failing

Comment: Yes I understand that the callback is trying to reach https, but I can’t change the behaviour of the browser and puma server to achieve my task. I also tried cleaning the cache of browser and hard reload, but nothing is working here.